# ezDXF Use Visibility parameters from an imported Block

Tags: ezdxf

I want to set the visibility parameters (VP) of a block  imported from a template DXF (V.2013). Using the Structure Browser I have found the VP are not saved with the block, they are in the object section. I guess importing the block is not enough. How can I import the VP of the block and how to set those VP in the inserted block?

Comment: What do you mean by "visibility parameters"?

Comment: You can build a block from several other blocks and add a visibility parameter to it. Once added you can give a name to each combination of hidden and visible block components. When you insert the block you can select the visibility parameter value for the insertion so the required  combination of sub-blocks is drawn.

Comment: Maybe you mean the DXF attribute "invisible" with group code 60: https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/dxfentities/dxfgfx.html#ezdxf.entities.DXFGraphic.dxf.invisible

Comment: I guess that binary attribute sets the visibility of the whole block. The visibility parameter allows to select by  name a combination of the visibilities of the sub-blocks comprised in the inserted block. It appears as the object BLOCKVISIBILITYPARAMETER in the DXF structure browser. It does'nt appear in the objects list of the Autodesk DXF reference online, so i guess this is why  it's not implemented in ezdxf. Inserting one of these blocks with ezdxf, all component blocks are made visible. I will have to make families of simple blocks, one for each value of the visibility parameter.

Comment: These are undocumented features like Dynamic Blocks and Block Parameters. These features are beyond the scope of `ezdxf`, it's too much work to reverse engineer them and I would have to rent AutoCAD, which I will never do again.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help. ezdxf is a great library!